# Help with Elmah Configuration in ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, dotnetnuke, elmah

I'm trying to setup [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) to log errors for our application.  I have successfully added the modules and am having no problems loading the ErrorLog page (elmah.axd).  However, Elmah isn't logging any test exceptions that I'm generating.

My web.config looks like this:

```
<configSections>
    <!-- Other stuff -->
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
        <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah"/>
        <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
        <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<elmah>
    <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data" /> 
</elmah> 

<httpHandlers> 
    <!-- Other stuff -->
    <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah"/>
</httpHandlers>

<httpModules>
    <!-- Other stuff -->
    <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah"/>
    <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
    <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah"/>
</httpModules>
```

Hitting the test exception page `http://localhost/elmah.axd/test` generates a [yellow screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow_Screen_of_Death#ASP.NET), but no log entry.

Between the sample provided and the tutorial on [DotNetSlackers](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/ErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlers.aspx) I can't see anything wrong.  Is there something I'm missing?  I've also attempted to generate errors via [Signaling](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/DotNetSlackersArticle#Error_Signaling), but that's not working either.

I am running this against DotNetNuke, and so that's where I'm currently thinking the problem lies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you need is to do is disable custom error messages in DotNetNuke.
1. Log on dnn Portal as host
2. Navigate to Host > Host Settings. 
2. Go to the Basic Settings - Appearance section. 
3. At Use Custom Error Messages, uncheck the check box. 
4. Click Update.
This will disable DotNetNuke's error handler.

Answer (score 1):

Could be that DNN is swallowing the exceptions - does it have its own Exception handling mechanism?

I was using ELMAH with Monorail and ran into a similar issue - [Castle MonoRail & ELMAH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275810/castle-monorail-elmah)

FYI [Someone else](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Forums/tabid/795/forumid/160/threadid/266910/scope/posts/Default.aspx) with the same problem.

Comment: Yeah, I just stumbled on that link too!

Comment: I noticed in your question you used signaling to solve your problem -- even that isn't working on my box.

Comment: Afraid I don't know too much about DNN, but have you tried disabling the DNN logging module?

Answer (score 1):

DNN does process all exceptions, so that's probably the issue you're seeing.  I believe it handles the Error event at the application level, logging everything to the database.  I don't know of any way to turn this off, but I've never really tried that hard, either.

Comment: Ya, it's figuring out how to turn it off that's the trouble.  DNN documentation is poor at best!